# Passing multiple dropdownlist items between pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use Asp.Net MVC. I have 4 dropdownlist in my page.

1- Car Company (40 items)
2- Model (30 items)
3- Year (20 items)
4- Engine(20 items)

when user select this item go to details page.In details page i want fill ddl and select item user was selected.

I have some ideas about this but i am not sure its right way.

1- post dropdownlist to controller and return back to detail page

2- write dropdownlist to cookie

or any other ideas ?

Comment: If you can use a 3rd party solution you can look into Knockout, wich lets you bind to arrays much like you describe: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view model like this

```
public class FilterVM
{
  public List<SelectListItem> Makes{ set;get;}
  public int SelectedMake { set;get;}

  public List<SelectListItem> Models { set;get;}
  public int SelectedModel { set;get;}

  public List<SelectListItem> Years{ set;get;}
  public int SelectedYear { set;get;}

  public List<SelectListItem> Engines{ set;get;}
  public int SelectedEngine { set;get;}

  public FilterVM()
  {
    Makes=new List<SelectListItem>();
    Models=new List<SelectListItem>();
    Years=new List<SelectListItem>();.
    Engines=new List<SelectListItem>();
  }
}
```

Now in your GET action

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
  var vm=new FilterVM();
  vm.Makes=LoadMakesFromSomewhere();
  return View(vm);
}
private List<SelectListItem> LoadMakesFromSomewhere()
{
  var lst=new List<SelectListItem>();
  lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Ford"});
  lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Honda"});
  return lst;
}
```

And in your view which is strongly typed to your FilterVM. We will write some javascript to handle the change event of the dropdowns so that it will read the selected item value and send an ajax request to get the content for the next dropdown .

```
@model FilterVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <label>Make</label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedMake,Model.Makes,"Select")

  <label>Make</label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedModel,Model.Models,"Select")

  <label>Make</label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedYear,Model.Years,"Select")

  <label>Make</label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedEngine,Model.Engines,"Select")

  <input type="submit" />
}
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    //code to load Models dropdown when user selects Make
    $("#SelectedMake").change(function(){
     var items="";
     $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetModels","Car")/"+$(this).val(),function(res){
         $.each(function(index,item){
           items+="<option value='"+item.ID+'>"+item.Name+"</option>";
         });
         $("#SelectedModel").html(items); 
     });
    });

    //Write other dropdown  filling code like above       
 });
</script>
```

Now you should have a `GetModels` method which accepts the Selected Make's ID and returns the models in JSON format.

```
public ActionResult GetModels(int id)
{
  var modelList=repositary.GetModelsFromMakeID(id);
  return Json(modelList,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Your JSON which you are returning should look something like this (and ID and Name in each item.

```
[
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "Name": "Accord"
    },
    {
        "ID": 5,
        "Name": "CRV"
    }
]
```

Write the change event handler for other dropdowns also. Finally when the user posts the form, you can check the SelectedMake,SelectedModel,SelectedYear property values.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(FilterVM model)
{
  check for model.SelectedMake, model.SelectedYear etc..
  //to do : Get result and show in a view/redirect.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewBag,ViewData or TempData object to hold such values